# Firebase Phone Authentication issues missing-client-identifier error when using Play Integrity API

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

When registering / signing in with Firebase phone authentication the authentication flow always launches the reCAPTCHA flow and after getting back into the app it issues a `missing client identifier` error.

My setup previously worked with the device verification / Safety Net apis.

The issue appeared without any actual changes I'm aware of except firebase dependency updates in my pubspec.

I now use

```
firebase_core: ^2.10.0
firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
```

Downgrading the dependencies to

```
firebase_core: 2.8.0 
firebase_auth: 4.2.10
```

didn't help though.

What else I checked so far:

- I followed (again) all steps on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth
- I made sure to link the correct Google Cloud project on the Play Store Integrity API page
- I use the right `SHA-1` keys from the "Play Store Signing" page (for app bundle builds) in the Firebase Console for my app
- I made sure the correct `SHA-256 certificate fingerprint` from the "Play Store Signing" page is registered in the Firebase Console
- I registered the correct app in the Firebase console under the "AppCheck" menu (probably unrelated though)
- I checked the "Credentials" on the Integrity API management page and made sure all are set
- I tried to hardcode the latest firebase BOM in the Android gradle file but it didn't help
- I hardcoded version `21.1.0` of the Android Firebase Auth library in the Android gradle file but it didn't help
- I made sure that my Android Api key is not restricted to any apis for testing
- I made sure Chrome is installed on the device
- I downgraded the `androidx.browser:browser` dependency in the Android gradle file to `1.3.0` but it didn't help
- I checked that the `google-services.json` is up-to-date

Did I forget anything or did anyone experience a similar issue and solve it after switching to the Integrity API?

Or in other words: What can go wrong if the exact same setup works with the activated Device Verification API but not without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

The reason was that the Android App key at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials was restricted to Android apps:

[image]

And this caused an error in the reCAPTCHA flow because it needs the key presumably also in the browser. It needs to be set to `None`.

The other thing  - why it went and still goes into the reCAPTCHA flow in the first place is that there is an open incident on the Firebase side:
https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/UY1LTFan8X5oybhphzfV

Currently the Integrity API is not working as expected and that's also the reason why the code worked with the Safety Net Apis - at least as long it didn't have to go into the fallback / reCAPTCHA flow.

[image]

**UPDATE**: As of May 1st, 2023 this issue is now completely resolved and the Play Integrity API as well as the phone authentication are now working as expected.