# Firebase Phone Auth [auth/missing-client-identifier] error on release AAB (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-app-bundle

I have React Native app with Firebase Phone Auth.
It has multiple flavor/schema.
For testing purpose I've used TestFlight and App Distribution.
Till now everything was great, authentication worked as expected for any flavor/schema on Android/iOS.

In Android Studio I've generated release signed (with my upload key) APK and tested it on real devices and BrowserStack. No authentication issues with real and testing numbers.
I've generated release AAB with same upload key. Result - real numbers give me **[auth/missing-client-identifier]**

Logs from BrowserStack.
[image: BrowserStack logs]

[image: Generate bundle]

What I've done before asking the question:

- Firebase Console and Google Cloud Console projects have same **IDs** and **SHA-1**/**SHA-256**.
  Google Cloud Console project restriction switched to **none**.
- SHA-1/SHA-256 checked with **./gradlew signingReport** cmd and Google Play Console (app bundle uploaded but not active).
- SHA-1/SHA-256 from Google Play Console added to Firebase Console project.
- **implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"** added to build.gradle file.
- Project was cleaned and rebuilded. google-services.json re-downloaded.

One this I have no opportunity to try - enable **Device Check API**.
[image: Device Check API]
I'm not sure, but it should be deprecated.

I can't understand why I have no problems with release APK**(!)**, but release AAB phone authentication gives me [auth/missing-client-identifier] error.

Maybe I missed smth? I really need help, but not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about Play Integrity API.
According to documentation this should be added to **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
```

https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#integrate-in-app

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error "[auth/missing-client-identifier]" usually occurs when there is a mismatch between the client identifier used in your Firebase project & the one used inside your application.

Please check if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095409/19448419

If this issue is specific to BrowserStack, you can reach out to their support team as well.

Comment: App restriction and identifier were checked. Release APK works well, release AAB has auth issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but that was in Android Java project.

I had solve that with this.
**Google Play Console app Dashboard** > **Release ** > **Setup** > **App integrity** > App signing**

Now copy the SHA1 key and setup it in your firebase console.

I hope that will work for you. It's work for me.

Comment: I've tried this before - but error is same.
Perhaps I missed some steps.
I've added SHA1 from my upload key. Then AAB was uploaded to Google Play. After that I've added SHA1 from Google Play Console to Firebase console. After that I should re-download google-services.json and make new build?
So now I should have three SHA1 in Firebase project (dev/release/GooglePlayConsole)?

Comment: No need when you will upload a app in play console they will provide a new SHA1 key, not upload SHA1 key

Answer (score 0):

The idea is Firebase doesn’t recognize the release version of the app (the app production in google play)
Make Sure You add release signing key to firebase
You get the sh1 key from android studio
1-Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)

2-Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
3-Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)
4-Click on Tasks/Android
5-Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
then go to firebase project setting ->apps ->add sha1 key
it will work fine with all firebase services